# foreach only getting first result

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api, foreach

I know there is tons of similar issues that are similar to mine and i've gotten a few mixed answers but i am not sure which one will work with mine but my foreach is only returning one item from my json api I am getting.

JSON

```
{"categoryIndex":0,"page_count":2,"total_count":2,"product_list":[{"type":"EXTRACT","classifications":["SATIVA"],"brand":"BRAND ","description":"","active":true,"taxRate":0.0975,"test_result_url":"","attributes":{"total_doses":0,"mg_dose":"","cbd_ratio":"","total_cannabinoids_percentage":"","general":["ATTRIBUTE 1","ATTRIBUTE 2"],"flavors":["FLAVOR 2","FLAVOR 1"],"effects":["EFFECT 1","EFFECT 2"],"thc_percentage":"-.-","cbd_percentage":"-.-","terpenes_percentage":"-.-","size":"1G","medium":""},"images":{"large_image":"","cropped_image":""},"back_stock_inventory_quantity":510,"menu_title":"","last_update_date":"2017-12-18T09:52:36.842-08:00","secondary_tax_rate":0,"product_id":"39a928e2-ded1-11e7-8088-0a66b72be922","product_name":"STRAIN NAME","live_inventory_quantity":5,"sub_types":["FLOWER ROSIN"],"size_list":[{"barcodes":["dnny"],"type":"EXTRACT","size_id":"39b04857-ded1-11e7-8088-0a66b72be922","size":1,"live_inventory_quantity":5,"product_size_name":"STRAIN NAME","product_unit":"gram","primary_tax_rate":0.0975,"price_sell":36.446469}]},{"type":"MERCH","classifications":[],"brand":"","description":"","active":true,"taxRate":0.0975,"test_result_url":"","attributes":{"total_doses":0,"mg_dose":"","cbd_ratio":"","total_cannabinoids_percentage":"","general":[],"flavors":[],"effects":[],"thc_percentage":"-.-","cbd_percentage":"-.-","terpenes_percentage":"-.-","size":"MEN'S L","medium":""},"images":{"large_image":"","cropped_image":""},"back_stock_inventory_quantity":0,"menu_title":"","last_update_date":"2017-12-18T09:52:36.907-08:00","secondary_tax_rate":0,"product_id":"5bb24bec-e072-11e7-8088-0a66b72be922","product_name":"123","live_inventory_quantity":123,"sub_types":[],"size_list":[{"barcodes":["sLz3"],"type":"MERCH","size_id":"5bb946c2-e072-11e7-8088-0a66b72be922","size":1,"live_inventory_quantity":123,"product_size_name":"123","product_unit":"count","primary_tax_rate":0.0975,"price_sell":112.072893}]}]}
```

my foreach

```
$response = wp_remote_get("xxx" );
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    $json = json_decode($body);


    /**** import products****/
    $product = array();
    $product_variations = array();



    if( ! empty( $json ) ) {

        foreach( $json->product_list as $key => $producttz ) {

            echo '<a href="'.testlink.'">' . $producttz->product_name . '</a>';


            $product[$key]['_product_id'] = (string) $producttz->product_name;
            $product[$key]['name'] = (string) $producttz->product_name;
            $product[$key]['description'] = (string) $producttz->product_name;
            $product[$key]['regular_price'] = (string) $producttz->price_sell;

            // Stock
            $product[$key]['manage_stock'] = (bool) $producttz->live_inventory_quantity;

            $data[$key]['products'] = $product;



            return $data; } }
```

I added on there `echo '<a href="'.testlink.'">' . $producttz->product_name . '</a>';` just to see if my foreach is looping through the results but its only returning the first one and its not returning the other ones. i know there is a few solutions but I am not sure which one will work for mine.

thank you in advanced

Comment: Your end of the first loop does `return $data;` which will terminate the loop and return the first set of data.

Comment: thank you! i was slamming my head reading all these threads to figure out what i was doing wrong...that was simple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `return $data;` is inside `foreach()`, which terminates the loop  immediately after first iteration and only first data is returned.

Put it outside of `foreach()` loop and you will good to go.

Comment: that also works too lol. I actually tried removing the { } and adding the : and adding the endforeach; and it worked too...this thing took me 8 hours to figure out lol